# Hardware Error Upon Swapping RAM

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I was testing new sticks on an HP Elitedesk 800 GI board. Everything booted successfully until I placed the old sticks back in. Upon doing so, the board cannot pass POST, and external USB boots do not work either. New sticks in, the same result now. My BOIS is modded. I have checked both the old and new sticks on another board and they work fine.I also ran the same BIOS programming on another board and it is working fine. Why is this happening? And is there a potential solution to this, even if it involves tampering with the board itself?

Comment: Did you accidentally unplug something else? What POST beeps/messages do you get? Did you use protection?

Comment: No, I made sure to verify everything as it was & I did make sure to use protection. I do not have a manual on hand for my specific board, but it is beeping a generic processor error (5 times). which is odd because the CPU was replaced recently

Comment: What brand of BIOS is it? 5 beeps and a red light is a RAM issue...

Comment: The actual chip itself is a Nuvotom. The firmware actually on it is Phenoix

Comment: 5 beeps on Phoenix is a CPU error, as you mentioned earlier. And if you put the original ram in without installing the new ram, you still get 5 beeps? Did you reconnect the CPU power cable from the PSU?

Comment: Yes, the PSU connection is secure. Same code repeats

Comment: I know RAM definitely has a role here, because the CPU fan goes full speed after a minute or so.